# sending file and json in POST multipart/form-data request with axios

Tags: javascript, json, file, axios, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a file and some json in the same multipart POST request to my REST endpoint. The request is made directly from javascript using axios library as shown in the method below.

```
doAjaxPost() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = document.querySelector('#file');

    formData.append("file", file.files[0]);
    formData.append("document", documentJson);

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://192.168.1.69:8080/api/files',
        data: formData,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

However, the problem is when I inspect the request in chrome developer tools in the network tab, I find no `Content-Type` field for `document`, while for `file` field `Content-Type` is `application/pdf` (I'm sending a pdf file).

[image: Request shown in network inspector]

On the server `Content-Type` for `document` is `text/plain;charset=us-ascii`.

**Update:**

I managed to make a correct request via Postman, by sending `document` as a `.json` file. Though I discovered this only works on Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To set a content-type you need to pass a file-like object. You can create one using a `Blob`.

```
const obj = {
  hello: "world"
};
const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
const blob = new Blob([json], {
  type: 'application/json'
});
const data = new FormData();
data.append("document", blob);
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/sample',
  data: data,
})
```

Comment: I couldn't find a solution anywhere for so long, and you come almost instantly with the correct answer. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Where do you append the file here? Is it missing in this code sample?

Comment: @ElectRocnic — The entire answer is about generating the JSON file in memory and appending that. I didn't repeat the logic for reading a file from a file input because the question isn't about that (and the code to demonstrate that is already in the question).

Comment: Thanks I got it running anyways. The only missing line was for me `formData.append("file", file)` which I added and it works for me :)

Comment: Very useful. Thanks. On the server, how do I unpack the 'document'? I see that the blob is uploaded as well as the file. I don't want the blob to be uploaded. I just need to unpack 'document'. How do I achieve that ?

Comment: @abhisek — The blob **is** the file. You read it the same way you read any other file from a multipart form request style POST request (how you do that depends on your choice of server-side programming language and form data handling library)

Comment: @Quentin yea, figured that. I am using node server side. So the logic was like this: add blob -> upload -> read blob -> parse json -> add/update data -> delete uploaded blob

Comment: Thanx mate! quick, clear, easy. That's how I like it! :P

Comment: this creates a filename though, and many backends will interpret this as a file - which is not.

Comment: @Pithikos — While the browser might not have read a file to get the data, it used the data to create a file and send it to the backend. As far as the backend is concerned, is **is** a file. Treating it as a file will work. The question is specifically about a backend which expects a file to be sent to it.

Comment: How do I read the Blob data in django?

Answer (score 18):

Try this.

```
doAjaxPost() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = document.querySelector('#file');

    formData.append("file", file.files[0]);
    // formData.append("document", documentJson); instead of this, use the line below.
    formData.append("document", JSON.stringify(documentJson));

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://192.168.1.69:8080/api/files',
        data: formData,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

You can decode this stringified JSON in the back-end.

Comment: but the backend receives blob as the string of object like '[object Object]'.

Answer (score 4):

You cant set content-type to `documentJson`, because non-file fields must not have a `Content-Type` header, see [HTML 5 spec 4.10.21.8 multipart form data](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#multipart-form-data).

And there`s two way to achieve your goals:

- JSON.stringify your data, and decode it in the back-end like [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64613695/12395601)
- pass a file-like object and set `Content-Type` like [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50774380/12395601)

Answer (score 1):

you only need to add the right headers to your request

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://192.168.1.69:8080/api/files',
  data: formData,
  header: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
    })
```

Comment: My header fields were already correctly set. The problem was `Content-Type` in the payload.

Comment: yes precisely in the request it is written text/plain when there should be multipart/form-data

Comment: This will override the Content-Type for the multipart data, discarding the boundary parameter and breaking the ability of the server to parse it. It won't have any effect  on the Content-Type for the "document" part of that multipart data.

Answer (score 0):

we can use **new Blob()** and  **JSON.stringify()** method to stringify json object and append to FormData, file data we can able to directly append to form data in the following way

```
function multiPart(payload) {
    const formData = new FormData()
    if (payload?.files.length > 0) {
        let attachments = []
        payload?.files.map(item => {
            item.attachmentList = item.attachments.map(d => d.name)
            item.attachments = item.attachments.map(d => new File([ d ], `${item.accountId}#${d.name}`, { type: d.type })) // if we need to update file name 
            attachments = attachments.concat(item.attachments)
            item.attachments = item.attachmentList.map(d => ({name: d}))
            return item
        })
        attachments.forEach(d => { formData.append('fileNames', d) })
    }

    const stringfiedJson = new Blob([ JSON.stringify(payload) ], { type: 'application/json' }) // important to mention type
    formData.append('postJson', stringfiedJson)

    return formData
}
const modifiedPayload = multiPart(payload)


axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/user-data',
    data: modifiedPayload
})
```