# Different Content-Type set in header in react native and on the web by axios

Tags: react-native, web, axios

I tried to upload a file using axios in react-native and on the web using the following sample code

```
const obj = {
            hello: "world"
        };

const json = JSON.stringify(obj);

const blob = new Blob([json], {
        type: 'application/json'
        });

const data = new FormData();

data.append("document", blob);

axios({
  url: 'SOME_URL',
  method: 'POST',
  headers:{...}
            },
  data: data
 })
 .then(res => console.log(res))
 .catch(res =>  console.log(res))
```

On react-native it is setting the content-type as "text/plain" but when I tried on the web it is setting the correct content-type as "multipart/form-data".

I tried setting Content-Type : 'multipart/form-data' but still it reverts back to text/plain in react-native.

I did follow this link 
[sending file and json in POST multipart/form-data request with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774176/sending-file-and-json-in-post-multipart-form-data-request-with-axios?rq=1) but it didn't work on react-native

Can anyone help on how to upload a file and a json along with it in react-native ?

Answer (score 0):

In here you can add key value pairs and objects in to the `FormData` object. In your case the `data`. According to your question you want puta file and a json file.

So you can add you file like this.

```
data.append('you_file_input_tag_name', formFile);
```

You can add you json to this data object again like below. Imagine your json object is in the variable name called `myjson`

```
var stringifiedDetail = JSON.stringify(myjson);
data.append('details', stringifiedDetail);
```