# How do you post a file along with some other data using axios react?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

So my model looks like this.

```
# posts/models.py 
from django.db import models 

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.TextField() 

    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/') 

    def __str__(self): 

        return self.title
```

And I know you can upload file using axios like this

```
 fileUpload(file){ 
const url ='http://example.com/file-upload'; 

const formData = new FormData(); 

formData.append('file',file) 

const config = { headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' } } 

return post(url, formData,config)

 }
```

But I want to upload the image along with the title. How do I do that in axios?

Comment: I think this SO post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50774380/8448463

Comment: Instead of initialising and empty `FormData()`, initialise it with the form containing the input fields you need: `form = $('#my-form'); const formData = FormData(form)`.

Comment: But I'm using react how do I do form = $('#my_form') in react

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = new FormData();
var archive = document.querySelector('#file');
formData.append("file_location", archive.files[0]);
formData.append("title", archive.files[0].name);
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/files/data/', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
```