# FormData doesnt append other variables except file using Axios and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently, I am trying to send my FormData through Axios PATCH method and receive it on NodeJS server-side. Somehow it won't receive any parameters that have been sent when I do a console.log in NodeJS. Is it because I have it in a wrong format or how? I also have added body-parser to the NodeJS code.

**UserEdit.js**

```
submitEdit = () =>{
    const { user, user_id, usernameInput, firstnameInput, lastnameInput, imageInput, emailInput, relogin, selectedFileName } = this.state

    console.log(selectedFileName);

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile);
    data.append('usernameInput', usernameInput);
    data.append('firstnameInput', firstnameInput);
    data.append('lastnameInput', lastnameInput);
    data.append('emailInput', emailInput);
    data.append('imageInput', selectedFileName);
    data.append('user_id', user.user_id);

const config = {
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
  };
    
axios.patch(`/users/edit/${user.user_id}`, data, config)      
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.statusText)
   })
}
```

**app.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./../frontend/src/images/uploads/",
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
     cb(null,"IMAGE-" + file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

app.patch('/users/edit/:userID', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const text = 'UPDATE users SET (username, email, first_name, last_name, user_img) = ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) WHERE user_id=($6)'
  const values = [req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.first_name, req.body.last_name, "IMAGE-" + req.body.imageInput, req.body.user_id];

  db.query(text, values)
       .then(() => {
        console.log("success!");
        // success;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
});
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    res.send(req.file);
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you check `usernameInput` and others if they have a non-empty value?

Comment: In UserEdit.js, when I alert all the values, it does come out. Only when it passed to the NodeJS, it's empty. @Anatoly

Comment: I think not to pass content-type. it's working without content-type.

Comment: I just tried that and it still won't work though, but the image file got uploaded to local storage, only other values still not received. @ZealousWeb

Comment: Please check >https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214371/not-getting-form-data-in-req-body-express-node-js

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that, I mean you should have to convert to blob. For an example:

```js
const data = { 
  username: usernameInput, 
  firstName: firstnameInput, 
  lastName: lastnameInput, 
  emailInput: emailInput, 
  selectedFileName: selectedFileName, 
  userId: user.user_id
}
data.append('data', new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
  type: 'application/json'
}));
```

Or if you still want to one by one, you can use this code below:

```js
data.append('usernameInput',  new Blob([usernameInput], { type: 'text/plain' }));
data.append('firstnameInput',  new Blob([firstnameInput], { type: 'text/plain' }));
data.append('lastnameInput',  new Blob([lastnameInput], { type: 'text/plain' }));
data.append('emailInput',  new Blob([emailInput], { type: 'text/plain' }));
data.append('imageInput',  new Blob([selectedFileName], { type: 'text/plain' }));
data.append('user_id',  new Blob([user.user_id], { type: 'text/plain' }));
```

Now, you can try your own.

Comment: I did the one by one method you provide, but it throws "ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set')". I'm not sure what that means, is it because of the JSON format? @titussutiofanpula

Answer (score 1):

To reduce your mistake, use a send request with postman, if your request is right, do 3 steps like photo, and `copy gerenated code foor Nodejs-axios`
[image]

I think your problem is about `header`, you can check and compare your request in code with request from postman