# How to update the status of order?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am trying to create e-commerce site. In which admin update the order status . Somewhere I found the logic for that but I am unable to update the status of orders in postman and unable to build front
end for that . Someone please help to resolve this ?

```
exports.updateStatus = (req, res) => {  
    Order.updateOne(
       { _id: req.body.orderId },
       { set: { status: req.body.status } },
       { new: true },
       (err, order) => {
       if (err) {
           return res.status(400).json({error: "Cannot update order status"});
       }
       res.json(order);
    });
};
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you elaborate what do you mean by status is not being updated? How are you testing this API? With postman or calling it from UI? Is status correctly being passed in `req.body`? Also, `unable to build front end for that` is very broad statement.

Comment: I am trying to update the status with postman but it not get update .

Comment: Can you log `res.body` and confirm if status is being set?

Comment: yes..  status  is not updated

Comment: Have you used express.json middleware in app.js file? If you can share code of app.js, it will help.

Comment: Show me the result of console.log(req.body)

Comment: { _id: '6018f659c195225bf879724e', status: 'Shipped' }  @MohammadYaserAhmadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on req.body use `req.body._id` instead of  req.body.orderId and no need to use `set` and `{new : true}` will return the modified document rather than the original. `updateOne` doesn't have this option. If you need response as updated document use `findOneAndUpdate`

```
exports.updateStatus = (req, res) => {  
    Order.findOneAndUpdate(
       { _id: req.body._id},
        { status: req.body.status } ,
       { new: true },
       (err, order) => {
       if (err) {
           return res.status(400).json({error: "Cannot update order status"});
       }
       res.json(order);
    });
};
```

Comment: I try this with frontend . it not working                        `export const updateOrder = (orderId, userId, token, order) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/order/update/${orderId}/${userId}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(order),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804442/formdata-doesnt-append-other-variables-except-file-using-axios-and-nodejs/65874765#65874765 Check my answer for this question, and copy javascript-fetch

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `{new: true}` option with the `updateOne` method.
This method does not support this option.

You should use `findOneAndUpdate` that supports `{new: true}` and returns the updated document (See [Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)).

So your code will look like:

```js
exports.updateStatus = (req, res) => {  
    Order.findOneAndUpdate(
       { _id: req.body.orderId },
       { set: { status: req.body.status } },
       { new: true },
       (err, order) => {
       if (err) {
           return res.status(400).json({error: "Cannot update order status"});
       }
       res.json(order);
    });
};
```