# Not able make post request to third party app

Tags: node.js, axios, cors, postman

I've written this code in my nodeJs backend

```
  const url = "localhost:8080/job/test/build";
  const username = "admin";
  const password = "116c197495ef372f129b85a8a2ca4aadc2";
  const token = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`, "utf8").toString(
    "base64"
  );
  const data = {
  }
  axios
    .post(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${token}`,
      },
    }) 
    .then((response) => res.send(response)).catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
```

I'm getting the following error

[image: The Error I'm getting]

The same request with same credential is working in postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `http` in url, like this"

```
 const url = "http://localhost:8080/job/test/build";
```

Comment: This seems to work but now the error has changed to  : "Error: Request failed with status code 403"
I'm a complete rookie in this though, don't have much idea

Comment: check my answer in this question, send a request with postman and copy request like answer and add http to url and test again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804442/formdata-doesnt-append-other-variables-except-file-using-axios-and-nodejs/65874765#65874765

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked. Really appreciate it!!