# How can i upload a file with custom name with multer-axios in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, multer

Im trying to upload a file with custom name with multer in nodejs

this is how i call from the frontend

```
const id = *some value*
Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/upload", formData, {headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
        .then((response) => {
            window.location.reload()
        })
```

And this in the backend

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, '../client/src/Images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Math.trunc(Date.now()/1000).toString() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{fieldSize: 1000000},
 })

app.post("/upload", upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    res.send("Image Uploaded")
})
```

Now the image is (correctly) saved with the name Date.now()/1000; but i want to saved with the name **id** that i have in the frontend, how can i pass that to multer?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774176/sending-file-and-json-in-post-multipart-form-data-request-with-axios

Comment: @JoaoLeal Not really, i don't know how to get the id that i send in the storage part yet